# Extended Access List Example

Tags: access-control-list

I want exactly 1 pc that can use udp in my network. How would i do this?

```
Router(config)#access-list 101 permit udp 192.168.100.111

Router(config)#access-list 101 deny udp any any
```

Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ACL has wrong syntax, it will not work.

You should use the right ACL syntax:

```
Router(config)#access-list 101 permit udp host 192.168.100.111 any

Router(config)#access-list 101 deny udp any any
```